# Mi codigo Javascript solo funciona en un objeto de una clase. En el resto de objetos con el mismo nombre de clase no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Tengo el siguiente script que entiendo es bastante básico. Yo soy muy novata en Javascript y no comprendo por qué no recorre todos los objetos con el mismo nombre de clase, en cambio solo funciona en el primero.

el script es el siguiente:

```
var postmodernmedia = document.getElementsByClassName("post-modern-media")[0];

 postmodernmedia.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
   postmodernmedia.classList.add("post-modern-media-phone");
})

postmodernmedia.addEventListener("touchend", function(){
    postmodernmedia.classList.remove("post-modern-media-phone");
})
```

El script lo que hace es crear un efecto "hover" en dispositivos moviles al tocar sobre una imagen modificando una clase *CSS* que le quita opacidad a la misma. Al quitar el dedo sobre la imagen, la misma se pone nuevamente opaca. Deberia funcionar en todas las imagenes que tengan el mismo nombre de clase *.post-modern-media* Pero solo funciona en la primera imagen del código HTML y en el resto no surje el efecto "hover".

¿que estoy haciendo mal en el script que no logro que recorra todas las imagenes con la misma clase para que surta el efecto en todas?

Comment: Que el codigo solo está aplicando al elemento [0]. Por eso solo funciona en el primero

Comment: Gracias Pipe por el aporte! Como bien dije, soy una completa novata en javascript jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice @Pipe en su comentario, debes alcanzar todos los elementos (actualmente alcanzas sólo uno). Igualmente, debes asignar el evento de escucha a todos los elementos.

Te aconsejo que en vez de `getElementsByClassName()` uses [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
/*
   OJO: con querySelectorAll se usa la notación: .nombreDeLaClase
*/

var postmodernmedia = document.querySelectorAll(".post-modern-media");

postmodernmedia.forEach(post => 
  post.addEventListener("touchstart", () => post.classList.add("post-modern-media-phone"))
)

postmodernmedia.forEach(post => 
  post.addEventListener("touchend", () => post.classList.remove("post-modern-media-phone"))
)
```